# Optional bean created after dependent service

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject an optional bean into a service. The bean is successfully created but consistently *after* the dependent service. Any thoughts why this goes wrong?

Spring Boot 2.5.0 is used. Without using the `Optional`, everything works fine.

Application.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Optional<SomeClass> someClass() {
        System.out.println("creating bean");
        return Optional.of(new SomeClass("someName"));
    }

}
```

SomeClass.java

```java
@Value
public class SomeClass {
    String name;
}
```

SomeService.java

```java
@Service
public class SomeService {

    public SomeService(Optional<SomeClass> some) {
        System.out.println(
                some.map(SomeClass::getName).orElse("empty")
        );
    }

}
```

Output:

```
empty
creating bean
```

Comment: Because it is optional. It will only be constructed at the moment it is needed. Also using `Optional` as a bean type should be avoided, you should only use `Optional` for the injection point.

Comment: In the real application, the bean creation may fail but I want the application to start regardless. That's why I made the `someClass()` method return an optional.

Also, isn't the output telling me that the bean is created *after* it is needed?

Comment: No it is created as soon as it is needed, when you call `map`. Returning `Optional` won't prevent the bean failure. Just return `null` (you already have a try/catch to handle the failure else you wouldn't be able to return the `Optional.empty`) and use `Optional` for the injection point. The behavior you see is due to the double `Optional`, as `Optional` is handled specially for injection points. While making an `Optional` bean is different than using `Optional` for the injection point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Works perfectly now.

I would accept the answer but I don't think I can because you posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When autowiring dependencies the `Optional` should be used at the injection point, to indicate that a bean might or might not be available. The bean cannot be available for different reasons (conditional configuration, or just a setup error leading to `null` for a bean).

Creating an `Optional` bean is something different then using `Optional` for the injection point.

Ideally, you would just create the bean, which would be created eagerly, if processing can fail, handle it and return `null`. Now when using `Optional` at the injection point it will see `null` and `Optional.empty()` will automatically be injected.